What was the first puzzle game with "undo reset"?
Some modern puzzle games (Stephen's Sausage Roll, Patrick's Parabox, A Monster's Expedition) let you "undo a reset": if you reset the puzzle and then press "undo", it will set the gamestate back to before you reset.
What was the first game with this feature?

Some emulators let you undo loading a savestate with their rewind feature, but I'm not sure that counts.
